# jquery can't receive special characters?

Tags: jquery, pdf, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I'm receiving filedata by jquery.  But the pdf files are corrupted...

For example:

```
%PDF-1.7
%????
1 0 obj
```

Needs to be this:

```
%PDF-1.7
%¡³Å×
1 0 obj
```

I make a httpresponse on the webserver with:

```
  FileStream fileStream = _FileProvider.Open(fileName);
  var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
  response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
  response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _FileProvider.GetLength(fileName);
```

And try to open it with:

```
var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileURL);
```

So how do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that the question marks in your example, second line, are really question marks or just - displayed as question marks because they are non-printable characters?

Comment: I retrieved the content from the pdf, whiich I downloaded from the browser with notepad++. So I quess it should be readable then? I compared it with the original.

Comment: hmm I can't really help further except to suggest maybe use wireshark to see the bytes going over the line so you at least know they are still correct there...